# wpa_supplicant.conf entries?

Tags: pi-3b+, wpa

Every resource I have seen / used always say how to COPY or paste entries into wpa_supplicant.conf.

The question is

Is there **a document actually explaining** , in "5 W's" style,  purpose these entries?

I am enclosing annotated entries in my wpa_supplicant.conf to illustrate my post questions.

This is an original with single network entry:

#default original /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
network={
        ssid="mywireless"
        #psk="secretpassphrase"
        psk=7b271c9a7c8a6ac07d12403a1f0792d7d92b5957ff8dfd56481ced43ec6a6515
}

#temporary commented out

Now what is the purpose of this ctrl_interface and where did it come from ?

#ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev

What are we updating and when ??

#update_config=1

Now for change - this is selfexplanatory 
 #country=US

```
#network={
```

#        ssid="testing"
   #        psk="jim"
   #        }

Comment: Which 'Software install' menu is that? Can't find it in the latest Raspbian Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Raspberry Pi the software release is contained in `/etc/os-release`. You can get it with:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/os-release
```

Comment: Thanks PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"

Comment: @JanHus Does my answer help you? Can you accept it?